# Chrome and SVG : unwanted scrollbars after zoomIn + zoomOut

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I use Chrome 15.0.874.106 m

My issue may be related to (but not quite the same) :
[Strange scrollbars around the svg background in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225797/strange-scrollbars-around-the-svg-background-in-chrome)
or 
[scrollbars in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665169/scrollbars-in-chrome)
Considering these other stackoverflow questions on Chrome+svg, i suspect a bug in chrome.

So my issue :
i include an svg in a simple html page.
Under chrome everything seems fine. When i zoom in, svg is correctly resized.
Issue is that when i zoomOut then, some ***unwanted*** scrollbars show right and below.
(as i use a mouse wheel, they sometime show only once every other mouse wheel click).
I tried to style overflow:hidden or overflow:visible : scrollbars are still there.
Whenever i reload, display is fine again : scrollbars disappear.

You can have a look at this test html file (if you use chrome !) :
http://www.akelai.fr/logo/

Any (easy) fallback solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the WebKit rendering engine, so the problem is reproducible in both Chrome and Safari. The bug has been fixed in Version 528+ on Nov 18, 2011, and I verified it is fixed in the most recent nightly build.
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43018

Hopefully that means the next major release of both Chrome and Safari will fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Dave.  I received last week the confirmation from chromium@googlecode.com that issue 107520 is now fixed. I can't +1 your answer as i don't have enough reputation, but you deserve it !